# Looking to boost the Wi-Fi with an extender or second router

Tags: wifi, router

My current setup is a *Virgin Media SuperHub* and a *CSL - 300 Mbit/s USB 2.0 WiFi Dongle*. I however am getting inconsistent connectivity just 5/6 Metres (down the hall) from the hub, and when I am connected I only get [~15MB/s download speeds](http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/4888218243) at the best of times, on a connection which has clocked 150Mb/s+ over a hardwire. I understand that I shouldn't expect speeds that high on 2.4GHz at a distance, but the SuperHub does provide 5GHz which is entirely unused at the moment.

This leads me to my question, what would be the best way to utilise the unused band? I have been looking into Range Extenders, such as the [NETGEAR EX6150](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00V6B9XS2/), but I also came across some [articles](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/network-wifi/how-set-up-router-as-repeater-3494655/) mentioning that you can just set up a router to act as an extender. This second option looks preferable, and cheaper.

The solution I'm hoping for would allow me to connect my Desktops (2 of them) to the network via a hardwire to the second router (acting as an extender) as well as improving connectivity for my other devices (phone & laptop).

What routers are there that are capable of this? It must:

- act as a wireless repeater for an existing network
- be under or around £60 ($85)
- bonus points if it can be a standalone router too
- have wired Ethernet (minimum x2) and wireless output capabilities
- be able to use the 5GHz band

Comment: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6232/range-extender-via-ethernet-rather-than-wifi